# Append a pandas dataframe to an existing excel table

Tags: python, dataframe, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I need some help with the following.
I currently use python pandas to open a massive spreadsheet every day (this spreadsheet is a report, hence every day the data inside the spreadsheet is different). Pandas dataframe allows me to quickly crunch the data and generate a final output table, with much less data than the initial excel file.
Now, on day 1, I would need to add this output dataframe (3 rows 10 columns) to a new excel sheet (let's say sheet 1).

On day 2, I would need to take the new output of the dataframe and append it to the existing sheet 1. So at the end of day 2, the table in sheet1 would have 6 rows and 10 columns.

On day 3, same thing. I will launch my python pnadas tool, read data from the excel report, generate an output dataframe 3x10 and append it again to my excel file.

I can't find a way to append to an existing excel table.
Could anybody help?
Many thanks in advance,
Andrea

Comment: This is actually several tasks: read data from an excel file, append data to it, and then write the result to an excel file. Which are you asking for help with, and what have you tried?

Comment: I can read data from an excel file and elaborate it with pandas. I don't know how to save it at the bottom of the current excel table though. Thanks

Comment: As I said, the appending should occur in Pandas: you read the excel table into a dataframe, append *to the dataframe*, and then replace the excel table with the appended dataframe. You're not directly appending to the excel table.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [openpyxl's utilities for dataframes](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html) then you should be able to do everything you need with the existing workbook, assuming this fits into memory.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb = load_workbook("C:\Andrea\master_file.xlsx")
ws = wb[SHEETNAME]
for row in dataframe_to_rows(dt_today):
    ws.append(row)
```

Comment: so basically if I have a small pandas dataframe, there's no way to append it at the end of the spreadsheet? meaning, there's no way open a spreadsheet, read how many rowa have a value in column A and add the dataframe at the end? ...

Comment: Where do you get that impression? `ws.append()` will always add rows to an existing worksheet.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry if my questions are too simple but I don't quite understand.
I have a pandas dataframe called df_today that has 3 rows and 8 columns.
I have a spreadsheet in C:\Andrea\master_file.xlsx
could somebody share the code that I need to have in order to add df_today at the bottom of my table inside the mater_file.xlsls? Thanks

Comment: Answer edited to include sample code. If you're still having problems I'd suggest continuing the discussion on the openpyxl mailing list.

Comment: thank you Charlie. is it possible that ws.append() doesn't save the change in the master_file.xls at the end?

Comment: Nothing is saved until you call `.save()` with a file name.

Comment: thank you Charlie. somehow I check the master_file.xls after the ws.append() instruction and nothing has been added to the file. My code is:

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb = load_workbook("c:\\master_file.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for row in dataframe_to_rows(output_df):
    ws.append(row)
wb.save('master_file.xlsx')

Comment: This is very difficult to discuss without the actual file.

Comment: I understand but it's a file of my firm and I can get fired if I upload anything. however, if you make a test with the code below, the master_file.xls shows up as empty at the end of the code :(

Comment: How big is the dataframe? A simple check of `ws.max_row` before and after will tell you whether any rows have been added. Check the timestamp of the file to make sure it has been altered (better still save under a different name).

Comment: omg, you know what was the problem? I was loading the file correctly, specifying the location of the file
wb = load_workbook("C:\Andrea\master_file.xlsx")
but then i was saving, specifying only the name and not the location, hence the file was saved correctly but in another folder :)
thank you so much Charlie

Comment: btw, one last question. would you know when using
for row in dataframe_to_rows(dt_today):
how to skip the header of the dataframe?

Comment: actually, I just found the solution -
for row in dataframe_to_rows(output_df, header=None):
thanks again

Comment: Handling of the header and indices is covered by the documentation to which I linked.

Comment: How can I define starting row. Because it begins writing 100. row