# pandas write to excel overwriting the existing excel rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to write the data to an excel and append a row to the same after each iteration:

```
        writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
        reader = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx')
        frame = i.to_frame().T
        l = len(reader)
        if l==0:
            frame.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True, sheet_name=country)
            writer.save()
        else:
            writer.book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
            writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
            reader = pandas.read_excel(r'test.xlsx')
            frame.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader) + 1)
            writer.save()
```

The first iteration just works fine but from the next iteration, it overwrites the previous iteration rows.
i get the data as series and that i convert into dataframe(frame) before writing to excel

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602533/append-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-existing-excel-table) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ExcelWriter` class in append mode (`a`). From the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                    mode='a') as writer:  
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')
```

You may need to rearrange your code if you want to guarantee that the file (if it exists) is overwritten on the first iteration, but is appended to on subsequent iterations:

```py
for (i, df) in enumerate(my_data):
    
    if i  == 0:
        mode = 'w'
    else:
        mode = 'a'

    with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                        mode=mode) as writer:  
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')
```

I am a bit confused what you are trying to achieve with the existing sheets, but I think you will need to specify explicitly to which sheet(s) you want the `DataFrame` to be written. You shouldn't need to re-write the other sheets.